# Spring Security Authorize request from native Postman app

Tags: rest, spring-security, postman-native-app

I am exploring/learning Spring security modules by implementing it through REST API.

To test the impact, we are using Postman native application as a rest client.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class Employee {

    @GetMapping("/status")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getStatus()
    {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("Resource is fetched", HttpStatus.OK);


        return responseEntity;
    }

}
```

above is a piece of resource for sake of consumption.
and below is the code snippet to configure Authentication and authorization

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("ashish").password("{noop}admin").roles("USER")
                .and().withUser("foo").password("{noop}foo").roles("ADMIN");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/status").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
        .formLogin()
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder()
    {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

now above authorization code is working fine when tried in browser - it uses its default spring login page.
however i am not quite able to understand how to execute/test the same through postman.

in method  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) , i tried removing formLogin() it did not work.
i added httpBasic - it also did not worked.

in postman, basic authentication is used by me.
[image: Postman Screenshot of Error]

while searching on internet, i came across some really good articles but almost all of them uses some sort of UI technology like angular or thymleaf to demonstrate the concept which i am finding hard to grasp.

I am referring below video tutorials to learn spring security.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=payxWrmF_0k&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTYTEooakHchTGglSvkZAjnE&index=6&t=0s

Thanks in advance!
Ashish Parab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do a `GET` request `http://localhost:8080/login` via postman and it will return you an html.  Extract the `_csrf` token from the response. It will look like

```
   <input name="_csrf" type="hidden" 
          value="1c470a6c-dff3-43aa-9d08-d308545dc880" />
```

2. Do a POST request as follows to `http://localhost:8080/login`, copying the `_csrf` token, username and password as form params

[image]

3. Take note of the `JESSIONID` `Cookie` value in the response from step two. And that is the session Id of the `authenticated session`.
4. As long as you sent the `JESSIONID` in subsequent requests as a cookie, spring security knows who you are. Postman will add that `Cookie` automatically to subsequent requests.
5. you can add it manually as header with that cookie header or update the postman settings to always send `JESSIONID` cookie

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement JWT token for the same and add it to the request header 'Authorization' in Postman. You can take a look at Java Brains Spring security videos on youtube.